# Liferay Simple File Upload instead of Complex Document & Media Page

Tags: liferay

I am creating one application in Liferay 6.2, it contains the Dynamic Data List which has Document & Media element associated with it. All work well but when user press Select button it open complex page for uploading the file. Which required lot of steps to upload single file.

Can this be simplified using hook; on pressing select it just open window to browse file as it is there in html, as currently functionality is confusing to client. And even file upload work automatically for guest users.

Any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can handle this with PortletUploadRequest by multipart form using file upload.